# Converting a value with object type, declared as List<T> to List<U> using Dictionary<Type, Type> with the types corresponding to T and U respectively

Tags: c#, generics, json.net, type-conversion, system.reflection

I am refactoring on a legacy code where back compatiblity is critical. I got stuck in trying to develop a converter for more than 40 different types to be serialized.

I need to convert `List<T>`s to `List<U>`s where the `U = TypeDictionary<Type,Type>[T]`.

I did a lot of search, and worked on the issue for two days. Still I couldn't reached to a sloution, maybe due to not knowing right keywords and I feel got lost. I would appreciate any advice.

**EDİT:** The problem was different from what I initially assumed. The problem was converting a variable which has actual type Object and declared type List<> into actual List<> type. Excuse me for misleading.

This is the static class I use to copy the properties of a class:

```
public static class PropertyCopier
    {
        public static U CopyFrom<T, U>(T source, U target)
        {
            var targetObj = Activator.CreateInstance<U>();
            foreach (var targetProp in targetObj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var sourceProp = source.GetType().GetProperty(targetProp.Name);
                if (sourceProp == null)
                {
                    var sourceField = source.GetType().GetField(targetProp.Name);
                    if (sourceField == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("there is no field or property with same name");
                    }
                    targetProp.SetValue(targetObj, sourceField.GetValue(source));
                }
                else
                {
                    targetProp.SetValue(targetObj, sourceProp.GetValue(source));
                }
            }
            return targetObj;
        }
    }
```

I defined a class using Json.Net; "CustomTypeConverter : JsonConverter".
These three private methods and the dictionary are the members of the CustomTypeConverter:

```
Private Dictionary<Type,Type> TypeToProxy = new Dictionary<Type,Type>();

private bool isGenericList(Type type)
    {
        return (type.IsGenericType && (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)));
    }

private Type GetFirstArgumentType(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }

private List<U> ConvertListToProxy<T, U>(List<T> source, U target)
    {
        var lst = source.Select(x => PropertyCopier.CopyFrom(x, target)).ToList();
        return lst;
    }
```

and this is a section from the WriteJson method of CustomTypeConverter

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    //..
         if ( isGenericList(value.GetType()) )
            {
                Type listType = typeof(List<>);
                listType.MakeGenericType(GetFirstArgumentType(value.GetType()));
                var newVal = Convert.ChangeType(value, listType);
                var newList = ConvertListToProxy(newVal, TypeToProxy[value.GetType()]);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, newList);
            }
    //..
    }
```

This is the screenshot showing the error message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXWpj.png)

Comment: Are you trying to create something like AutoMapper?

Comment: What if you just declare the types `ConvertListToProxy<object, Type>(newValue, TypeToProxy[value.GetType()])`. I must be missing something though, because I can't see why it wouldn't be inferred

Comment: Yes, I think I am trying to create something like AutoMapper for Json serialization. I may be in a wrong direction.

Comment: @itsdaniel0 Thank a lot for your comment. I modified the approach. Removed the Type parameters and worked with objects. I recalled that casting any object to object type doesn't change the object itself only the identity of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I solved the problem thanks to the suggestions and help I took from you.

Edit: I used dynamic type to skip type checking and types are taken by using Reflection methods. The type transformation is handled via a wrapping method PropertyCopier.ProxyFrom.

```
public List<dynamic> ConvertListToProxy(dynamic source)
    {
        // source is List<>
        Type T = source.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
        Type U = _typeToProxy[T];
        List<dynamic> target = new List<dynamic>();
        try
        {
            foreach (dynamic item in source)
            {
                target.Add(PropertyCopier.ProxyFrom(item, U));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            Logger.Get().WriteLine("***-Exception-***");
            Logger.Get().WriteLine($"***-Trying to convert to List<{U.Name}>");
            Logger.Get().WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Logger.Get().WriteLine($"-***");

        }
        return target;
    }
```

And the calling section of the WriteJson method is modifed like this:

```
 if (isGenericList(value.GetType()))
            {
                var newList = ConvertListToProxy(value);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, newList);
            }
            else
            {
                if (_types.Contains(type))
                {                    
                var newObj = PropertyCopier.CopyFrom(Convert.ChangeType(value, type), _typeToProxy[type]);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, newObj);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a shorter code, you can use:

```
var firstArgumentType = GetFirstArgumentType(value.GetType());
newList = value.ConvertAll(x => Convert.ChangeType(x, _typeToProxy[firstArgumentType]));
```

But, you need to change more code for this.
I can give you a working example in this site:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/4CmvzR

You can also run the code in this website.

Comment: It was my fault that I defined the question in a wrong way. Your solution is the answer of the question I asked. Later I realised that the problem was converting an object to List<>. Thanks for your help, You led me to the right direction.